# SpringBoot with Spring SAML / Spring Session: New Session is Created After Authentication with IDP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-saml, spring-session

**Problem Overview**

I have a Spring Boot 2.0 application acting as a service provider (SP) using Spring SAML.  As I need to have multiple instances of the service deployed within my environment, I'm using Spring Session's JDBC session to provide a centralized session store.  Upon accessing the discovery URL page within this SP, I see exactly one session created.  Multiple access utilize the same session and I see the session's LAST_ACCESS_TIME updated and I see a SESSION cookie created for my domain of "app.localhost".  After successfully authenticating with IDP (and being redirected back to my SP), a *new* session is created and the SAMLResponse fails to be completely processed, as the associated SAML context stored in the HTTP session is associated with the previous session (and still resides in database).

I'm using the Spring Boot SAML SP reference implementation, per: [SpringBoot SAML](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample)

For IDPs, I've tried ssocircle.com and samltest.id and I get a new session when being redirected back to my SP.  It appears the existing cookie is no longer available to the SP after redirect.

I've verified SESSION cookie is part of the domain I have setup, "app.localhost".

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm trying to get multiple instances of this SP working.

[@Vladimír Schäfer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510410/vladim%C3%ADr-sch%C3%A4fer)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging and inspecting the session cookie created by Spring Session, by setting the SameSite cookie attribute to empty string (i.e., unset), I was able to get passed a new session being created when being redirected from IDP.

I created the following Spring Session cookie serializer:

```
@Bean
public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
    DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    serializer.setSameSite("");
    return serializer;
}
```